# Find $\mathbb E(X | X + 2Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ ~ $U[0,1]$

Tags: conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ two independent random variables with unifrom distribution $U[0,1]$. Need to find $\mathbb E(X | X + 2Y)$. Is my calculation below correct?

$\mathbb E(X | X + 2Y) = \mathbb E(X|X) + \mathbb E(X | 2Y) = X + 2\mathbb E(X|Y) = X + 2*\frac{1}{2} = X +1$

Comment: There is no linearity in the second argument for conditional expectation. You will need something different. A way to see that this is wrong is : how can $E(X | X+2Y)$ have support outside $[0,1]$, which is what $X+1$ seems to indicate?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, I saw it, thanks. How else to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+2Y]+\mathbb{E}[Y|X+2Y]+\mathbb{E}[Y|X+2Y]=\mathbb{E}[X+2Y|X+2Y]=X+2Y$$

Being

$$X \perp\!\!\!\!\!\! \perp Y$$

they are exchangeable too, thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+2Y]=\frac{X+2Y}{3}$$

---

Alternative solution:

Looking at the following drawing[image]

and setting $U=X$ and $Z=X+2Y$

- If $0<z<1$ $X$ is uniform in $(0;z)$ with expectation $\frac{z}{2}$
- If $1<z<2$ $X$ is uniform in $(0;1)$ with expectation $\frac{1}{2}$
- If $2<z<3$ $X$ is uniform in $(z-2;1)$ with expectation $\frac{z-1}{2}$

Thus the expected value is

$$\frac{z}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z-1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{2z+1}{8}$$

Comment: If $X+2Y=1.2$, then $X$ can be any number from $[0,1]$, so its expected value is $1/2$

Comment: Yes.  The condition $X+2Y=z$ restricts the possible $(x,y)$ values from the whole unit square down to a line segment with slope $-1/2$.  So long as $z$ is between $1$ and $2$, the line segment covers the full width of the square, and $\mathbb{ E}(X)=1/2$

Comment: @Empy2 : I followed your hint....can you please check my answer? (I cannot delete it because it was accepted)

Comment: I agree with the picture and calculations, until I think they should remain three different formulas, depending on the value of $z$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that example can hint you :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X|X+Y]+\mathbb E[Y|X+Y]=\mathbb E[X+2Y|X+Y]=X+Y
\end{align*}
But by symmetry $\mathbb E[X|X+Y]=\mathbb E[Y|X+Y]$ which means that $$\mathbb E[X|X+Y]=\frac{X+Y}{2}$$

Comment: It is $X+2Y$, not $X+Y$, but I think something similar works.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+2y$.  Draw a graph with $x$ on the horizontal and $z$ on the vertical.  Find the region in the plane that can be reached by $(x,z)$.  It should be a parallelogram.
Draw horizontal lines through the region, finding the intervals of allowed $x$ values for each $z$ value.
The midpoint of an interval is the expected $x$-value for that $z$-value.